# HHVM in a production environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, hhvm

We are building a new PHP project, and we heard of the new HHVM, we wanted to deploy our application on it, but we are not sure if it is ready for production environments or not?

We have a laravel 4 application with MySQL and MongoDB as the databases.

Our application is concerned alot about performance and speed of requests because it is a financial application.

Is HHVM production ready ? if it is not and we should wait, how easy will it be to migrate to it after we are live when it becomes production ready, will it break our code? and most of all will PHP be on HHVM for a good while after hack is in town ?  is there any live examples of it (other than FB)?, We really like HHVMs performance, but we can't risk the whole project goin down after production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion:

I simply don't trust such a new one (Hack) and can't risk until it's become available or accepted by the community. It's not sure whether it'll gain trust or not. You are going to reduce the support for your project if you need any during the development, not enough resources and fellow developers, AFAIK.

I think, It's risky and you should think again about it. An article about [Hack](http://heera.it/facebook-hack).

Comment: ok and what about HHVM itself as a php runtime ? can we use it ?

Comment: If you don't have other option, I'll stick with common one, used by more people, at least i'll get more support from more people.

Comment: So bottom line is use my same old PHP runtime,and if HHVM makes it to production, we can just move to it as it's just another run time and shouldn't make an issue as it is expected, am I right ?

Comment: That's 100% right :-)

Comment: Well, just let be matured enough.

Comment: Ok will I think you are right, it does support all of the major frameworks or the extensions yet, so when It becomes more mature, we can just switch our runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot WereWolf for your help.

Comment: I can understand your concern.  But, it now supports the top 20 frameworks.  I have been using it with Laravel and it has been quite usable and stable.  Been a few things I had to work around but nothing even close to major.

Answer (score 3):

I do not risk moving my current project to it yet, but I plan to enable CI-tests using HHVM (parallel to usual PHP-5.5 tests) really soon. This way I will know when the project is compatible and plan transition

Comment: I like the HACK but still can't trust it and why should I risk while it's not necessary.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha you definitely shouldn't "while it's not necessary". I just expect that it will become necessary performance-wise at some point.

Comment: Yes I agree with you and that's what I meant :-)